# Regular expression matches both numbers and units

Tags: python, regex

I have some input, which includes lines like:

```
5feet
23m^2
7 m/s
```

I'd like to rewrite these as:

```
5 feet
23 m^2
7 m/s
```

And for that I could use:

```
re.sub(r"([0-9])(?=[a-zA-Z])",r"\1*","5feet")
```

However, I also have numbers which look like:

```
23e-7
58.234e-200
```

which are matched by the above pattern.

Is there a way to have the regular expression somehow match the first group, but exclude the second?

Comment: Are they each on their own line?

Comment: Would `r"([0-9.])(?=[a-zA-Z])(?!e-[0-9]+)"` work for you?

Comment: you have a problem with numbers in **scientific notation e**? could you have `8.198e9feet` or `2.443e-3m` ?

Comment: Yes, @kaᵠ, that expresses it well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tack on a *negative* lookahead assertion `(?!...)` (the opposite of `(?=...)`) to exclude that case:

```
re.sub(r"([0-9])(?=[a-zA-Z])(?!e[+-]?\d)",r"\1*","5feet")
```